# error cargar una imagen en yii2

Tags: post, yii2, fileupload

buenas tardes mi proyecto tiene un modelo client, un controlador clientController y un form me guie en la documentacion de Yii2 pero no doy con el problema ya que me guarda todos los campos pero no me carga la imagen en la ruta que le indico, no se genera el REquest post.

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;



class Client extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
 public $image;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'client';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'country'], 'required'],
        [['name', 'country'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'idclient' => 'Codigo Cliente',
        'name' => 'Nombre',
        'country' => 'Pais',
        'image' => 'Imagen',
    ];
}
public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->image->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . 
$this->image->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

mi controlador

```
 public function actionUpload(){
    $model = new Client();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');

        if($model->validate()) {

            if ($model->upload() !== false) {
                $model->save();
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

}
```

mi Formulario

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
 "method" => "post",
 "enableClientValidation" => true,
 "options" => ["enctype" => "multipart/form-data"],
 ]);
 ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la ruta

C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\uploads

valor del request POST

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el request file

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías poner el schema de tu tabla de la BD, y la ruta donde quieres guardar tu imagen, es decir raiz/frontend/uploads o raiz/uploads y si esa carpeta actualmente existe?

Comment: listo amigo, si necesitas mas informacion me avisas

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada el campo en donde se guarda la ruta de la imagen, es totalmente diferente al de la imagen donde se carga,

por lo que el campo que tienes en tu modelo debe llamarse de forma diferente

Así que deberías cambiar `public $image;` por `public $imageFile;` o algún otro nombre

En segunda, si no especificas el campo en alguna parte de las reglas no se va a guardar.

Si no quieres ponerle una regla en específico simplemente usa `safe`

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       [['name', 'country'], 'required'],
       [['name', 'country'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
       [['image', 'imageFile'], 'safe']
   ];
}
```

En tercera deberías verificar si existe la ruta en la que quieres almacenar, así que

```
public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        FileHelper::createDirectory(Yii::getAlias('@app')."/uploads", 0777);
        $this->imageFile->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@app')'/uploads/' .
        $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' .$this->imageFile->extension);
        $this->image = $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' .$this->imageFile->extension;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

En dado caso de que el alias `@app` no exisitiera, tendrías que agregarlo, para eso te dejo esta respuesta d ecomo crear aliases en un basic template
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file

Comment: Muchas gracias ya agregue la acotación y continua el problema.

Comment: Te guarda el campo de image, pero no te guarda la imagen en el server?

Comment: actualmente no esta haciendo nada me guarda el campo de la imagen en null y no mueve la imagen al directorio

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para que la revises

Comment: Hola amigo aplique los cambios y aun sigue el inconveniente

Comment: Te marca un error? guarda el registro? guarda la imagen, en dónde se queda?

Comment: le agregue una modificacion en las rules, y bueno no mueve la imagen ni guarda en la bd, puse esta rule    'uploadRequired' => 'No has seleccionado ningún archivo'    y entonces con esa excepcion es la que toma

Comment: A qué campo le agregaste esa rule, hasta dónde lelga el proceso?

Comment: al campo imageFile que fue el q me comentas que cambiara para indentificar la variable al campo en la bd simplemente me indica que no he cargado ningun archivo por que la regla que le puse

Comment: olvide mencionar que tu campo también lo debes editar
`<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput()?>`

Comment: ya amigo pero el post sigue sin enviarme el valor correcto de la url agregue en la imagen en reques post que me da yii

Comment: imageFile va a venir vacío porque envió una imagen, intenta hacer un print_r a `$_FILES` y pon le imagen que trae

Comment: ya lo agregue pero aun sigo con el problema de no capturar su url no mover el archivo

Comment: me había fallado cambiar el nombre de las variables en el upload, he editado la respuesta, modificala en tu código e puedes intentar de nuevo?

Comment: con esa rule pasa a la view pero ahora no guarda nada en $_FILE ni en el POST alli mande la foto de upload

Comment: en tu controller, arriba de ` return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);` pega `print_r($model->errors)` y pega lo que te trae

Comment: amigo agregue como me indicaste pero no se muestra nada anexe imagenes

Comment: debiste poner el die; después del print para que pudieras ver los errores

Comment: solo me trajo un array en blanco

Comment: podrías actualizar hasta el momento como tienes tu código?

Comment: Hola bn dia amigo en lo que tenga un chance te cambio al codigo nuevo lo que pasa es que se me he complicado con el trabajo, una pregunta como hago para migrar el proyecto de YII2 a otro server en otra maquina

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he logrado basandome en la guía de yii2 https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/input-file-upload , creo que el problema está en el lugar donde guardas la imagen que no es un directorio público, intenta guardandolo en el direcorio @web... Espero sea útil mi aporte... Saludos...